# how to add parameters with mulitselection enabled in ssrs 2008

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008, multipleselection

Well,

I have a table called Resource(ResourceId,ResourceName) and a table Session (SessionId, StartDateTime,EndDateTime,ResourceId)

I have a line chart that shows the count of sessions for a given month for each resource. so it will be something like

Count   Month   resourceid  resourcename 
10  Jan-2006    2   ResourceA
9   Jan-2006    1   ResourceB
3   Feb-2006    2   ResourceA
19  Feb-2006    1   ResourceB

So the question is imagine there are more resources. I create a new parameter for the report and bind it to the resource table, so that this parameter has a dropdownlist of resources. The problem is however i can only select a single resource, it can not be more than one. Like i can't select ResourceA and ResourceC to see a comparison of their session counts.

The question is, is there someway i have a parameter for the report which can select multiple values i.e. can select ResourceA and ResourceC and it shows me the line chart for these resources, then if i select ResourceD and ResourceX it shows me linechart for that.

Hope that helps.

Oz`enter code here`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are multi-value parameters available to you.  See the following: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337292.aspx